# python equivalent code for matlab histogram

Tags: python-3.x, matlab

I am manually trying to convert a matlab code to Python for my application. The Matlab code is this:

```
% BUILD HISTOGRAM

% Specify bin centers of the histogram
bin_c=-0.58:0.04:0.58;

% Three dimensional histogram of bivariate data 
Z = hist3(dRRnew, {bin_c bin_c});

Z(14,15:16)=0;
Z(15:16,14:17)=0;
Z(17,15:16)=0;
```

Can I get some help in writing in the python equivalent code?

**Edited**

I used the matlab2python tool to convert matlab code to python and the resulting code was as follows:

```
# BUILD HISTOGRAM

# Specify bin centers of the histogram
bin_c = np.arange(- 0.58,0.58+0.04,0.04)

# Three dimensional histogram of bivariate data
Z = hist3(dRRnew,np.array([bin_c,bin_c]))

[X,Y]=meshgrid(-0.58:0.04:0.58, -0.58:0.04:0.58);
surf(X,Y, Z);
axis tight
xlabel('dRR(i-1)')
ylabel('dRR(i)')
```

But i checked the matplotlib docs, there is no in-built function hist3.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for [hist3d()](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html) that is part of the matplotlib package. I would also suggest carefully looking through what the translator has kicked out as I think you'll also have issues with [surf](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/gallery/mplot3d/surface3d.html) and xlabel and ylabel as well.

Comment: I checked hist3 of matlab, it basically returns the number of elements in each bin. `hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(dRRnew[:,0], dRRnew[:,1], bins=30*30,density=False)` will this not suffice in python?

Comment: @Jasmine that so long as you get out both sets of edges and a count of elements then seems like you’re all good 